# Processing audio signals in Matlab vs Sensor

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, sensors

I'm trying to do target recognition using the target acoustic signal. I tested my code in matlab, however, i'm trying to simulate that in C to test it in tinyOS using sensor simulator.

In matlab, i used wav records (16 bits per sample, 44.1 sample rate), so for example, i have a record for a certain object, lets say cat sound which of 0:01 duration, in matlab that will give me a total of 36864 samples of type int16 ,and size 73728 bytes.

In sensor, if i have [Mica2 sensor: 10 bits ADC (but i'll use 8 bits ADC), 8 MHz microprocessor, and 4 Kb RAM. This means that when i detect an object, i'll fill the buffer with 4000 samples of type uint8_t (if i used 8 KHz sample rate and 8 bits ADC).

So, my question is that:

- In matlab i used a large number of samples to represent the target audio signal(36864 samples), but in the sensor i'm limited to only 4000 samples, would that be enough to record the whole target sound?

Thank you very much, highly appreciate your advice

Comment: Four suggestions: you could cut some of the sample (doesn't necessarily have to be in one chunk); you could downsample; you could use a Fourier transform to compress; or you could extract a few key features (maybe a few of the strongest Fourier modes and the placement of transients in time) and use that for matching. If you are using correlation to find the signal, then I would simply try downsampling first.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes i'm actually doing framing and feature extraction and then do the matching based on the extracted features, however, i need to record the whole sound in order to do that, for that reason i was confused